# Extract pickled data

Tags: python, pickle

Is there a way to extract a file generated by pickle, while you don't even have the same classes as the original project that pickled it?

I'm trying to read a pickled file generated in an older project.  I don't have the source code of the old project.  But I would like to retrieve the data of the file, even as plain dictionaries.  Is there another solution or should I just use a binary editor?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in a pickle file to do this, even if your wrote your own unpickler from scratch.

Comment: Does the provided pickle disassembler do what you want?

Comment: This question came from the general impression that, when an object is pickled, the object class Python path (as a str) and the object attribute (as a dict) are both pickled.  I guess I just would have wanted to retrieve this attribute as a dict.  Of course I can still "mock" classes to let pickle do its work in dumb and empty classes, but I was curious if another solution existed.

Comment: @vincent-lg: Not all types are stored that way—a class can define a “reduced” representation to store from which its values can be reconstructed.  (The name of a class (or function) is itself an example of such a reduced form.)  The question about [`pickletools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html) stands.

Comment: This won't be trivial to implement, but yeah I had missed the note on `pickletools`, thanks!